# How to find closest point (point being (x,y), in a list of different points) to a given point?

Tags: c#, random, distance, points

Currently I have a random point being generated from Random. I am trying to check if the given random point is too close to any other existing points in the plane, if it is far enough away from ALL other points, it will be added to the list of other points. I start with one given point and the first hundered points in the list are being generated this way. My problem is, when I go to draw all the points on the list onto the screen, often the points are much closer than they should be allowed to be.

```
public void generateFirstMap()
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            int randXpixels = Main.rand.Next(24, Main.screenWidth - 16); //leave outer 16 pixels of screen empty (planet sprite has diameter of 8 pixels)
            int randYpixels = Main.rand.Next(27, Main.screenHeight - 27);
            Tuple<int, int> coord = Tuple.Create(randXpixels, randYpixels);
            if (distance(closestPoint(coord), coord) < 200)
            {
                continue;
            }
            points.Add(coord); //List<Tuple<int,int>> points;

            count++;
        } while(count < 100);


public Tuple<int, int> closestPoint (Tuple<int, int> p1)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> p2 = Tuple.Create(0, 0);
        bool firstRun = true;
            foreach (Tuple<int, int> point in points)
            {
                if (firstRun)
                {
                    p2 = point;
                    firstRun = false;
                }
                else if (distance(p1, p2) < distance(p1, point))
                {
                    p2 = point;
                }
            }
            return p2;
    }

public double distance(Tuple<int, int> p1, Tuple<int, int> p2)
    {
        Vector2 line = new Vector2((p2.Item1 - p1.Item1), (p2.Item2 - p1.Item2));
        return Math.Abs(line.Length());
    }
```

Edit: to be clear, the number for how close they can be is just a number I threw out there (for now) it can be anything >~30

Edit2: Changed all tuples to Vector2 and used suggested code, still hasn't changed the problem

Edit 3: Using a for loop to loop through all the points (inside of the while loops) and using break seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Why do you use `Tuple<T1, T2>` instead of `Point` or your `Vector2` class?

Comment: What does distance look like ?

Comment: I don't know the `Vector2` class... is `line.Length()` what you think it is, or does it always return 2?

Comment: hmm ok 1: use vector2 for all your points instead of tuple. 2: you are over complicating your find closest. you can do it in one line of linq points.Any(v=> (v - p).length < 200) 3: if you compare each new point against all other points it will become non performant as you get more pointa

Comment: There's no way this is going to work for any reasonably sized screen, assuming you want 100 points all to be a minimum distance of 200 pixels apart. You will need to rethink the entire premise of this!

Comment: @matthew, its the opposite, it wont accept any points within 200 pixels

Comment: @TimothyColemanHarrelson That's what I said - they need to be a minimum of 200 pixels apart, i.e. it won't accept any pixels closer than that. But see my answer below for code which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
public void generateFirstMap()
{
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        bool addPoint = true;
        int randXpixels = Main.rand.Next(24, Main.screenWidth - 16);
        int randYpixels = Main.rand.Next(27, Main.screenHeight - 27);
        for (int a = 0; a < points.Count; a++)
        {
            int dX = randXpixels - points[a].X;
            int dY = randYpixels - points[a].Y;
            if (dX * dX + dY * dY < 200)
            {
                addPoint = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(addPoint)
            points.Add(new Point(randXpixels,randYpixels));

        count++;
    } while (count < 100);
}
```

Just change the Point class to your tuple or whatever you are using

Comment: This worked :D, Im not sure why the for loop with a break statement worked better than continue, but thanks, this fixed the problem

Comment: The break is there because if you find even one point in your list that is closer then 200 you can stop checking the other ones and exit right away since addPoint will never get to be true again. If you mean the diffrence between break and continue: Break = stops the loop right there and exists it, continue = skip the current itteration at this point and continue with the next one

Answer (score 4):

This should do:
(Requires you to remove alls Tuples and replace them with the Vector2 type, which makes far more sense in general. Also you want to adjust your naming.

```
public Vector2 GetClosestPoint (Vector2 v1)
{
    return points.OrderByDescending(v2 => GetDistance(v1,v2)).First();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you'd want this to be fairly fast because it's a pretty slow algorithm (it's O(N^2) I think). An obvious optimisation is to just calculate the distance squared and use that to compare distances - this does away with a square root operation.

However you have a much more serious problem. If your OP is correct, then you are trying to place 100 points on a screen such that none of them are closer than 200 pixels apart. This is not likely to happen with randomly selected points, because the chances are that they will occur in positions such that after a number have been placed there simply isn't room for any more.

Anyway, here's some code which will attempt to calculate the points - but it will never terminate, because the points won't fit unless you make the screen VERY big. Try running it with different seeds for the `Random()` constructor and see what happens.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var points = new List<Point>();

            int screenWidth     = 1920;
            int screenHeight    = 1280;
            int numPointsWanted =  100;

            long nearestAllowedSquared = 200*200;

            Random rng = new Random(12345);

            while (points.Count < numPointsWanted)
            {
                int randXpixels = rng.Next(24, screenWidth - 16);
                int randYpixels = rng.Next(27, screenHeight - 27);
                var point = new Point(randXpixels, randYpixels);

                if (distanceToNearestPointSquared(point, points) >= nearestAllowedSquared)
                {
                    points.Add(point);
                    Console.WriteLine(points.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        private static long distanceToNearestPointSquared(Point point, IEnumerable<Point> points)
        {
            long nearestDistanceSquared = long.MaxValue;

            foreach (var p in points)
            {
                int dx = p.X - point.X;
                int dy = p.Y - point.Y;

                long distanceSquared = dx*dx + dy*dy;

                nearestDistanceSquared = Math.Min(nearestDistanceSquared, distanceSquared);
            }

            return nearestDistanceSquared;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the points in the plane and use [this](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php) formula to calculate the distance with the new random point you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Vector2 GetClosestPoint (Vector2 v1)
{
    return points.OrderBy(v2 => GetDistance(v1,v2)).First();
}
```

This is based on the top answer here at this time but will return the closest point rather than the furthest point (as the method name suggests). :-)